# Responsive in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I made an expandable `div` with `jQuery` so in my css the `div` is `250px` width and when i expand it is animated to `500px`.

How can i make it responsive? I mean when the `div` is "open" i want it so that when the user resizes his window the `div` resizes with it and also when the user clicks `open` on the div it opens depending within the window's
size.

Here is my code:

```js
$('.button').click(function(){

$('.content').animate({width: "500px",}, 500);
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.content').animate({top: "-400px", marginBottom: "0px", height:"1000px"}, 500);
},500);

});
```

```css
.content{
 width:250px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tibuakaw/of8znvc5/

Answer (score 1):

```
.content{
    width:50%;
}
```

play around with the width :)

Comment: actually i was thinking about make like 150% of the width into the javascript and like that make a media queries on the div like that the javascript properties take always 150% of the size but it' s really unstable :p

Comment: Check out this article: http://zerosixthree.se/detecting-media-queries-with-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

you need to use percentage instead of pixels when opening your div:

```
$('.content').animate({width: "80%",}, 500);
```

That will expand the div to be 80% the width of the page.

jsfiddle [here](http://%20jsfiddle.net/of8znvc5/1)